# How to continuous replicate data in background

Tags: ios, couchbase, couchbase-lite

In my ios app I have setup pull replication. Here is code

```
- (void) prepareCouchBaseAuthentication : (NSArray *)arrUserId {
NSError* error;

CBLManager* mng = [CBLManager sharedInstance];
CBLDatabase *database = [mng databaseNamed: kDatabaseScore error: &error];

if (!database) {
    [self showAlert: @"Couldn't open database" error: error fatal: YES];
    return;
}

NSURL* serverDbURL = [NSURL URLWithString: kServerScoreURL];


objAppDelegete.pull = [database createPullReplication: serverDbURL];
objAppDelegete.pull.continuous =YES;

objAppDelegete.pull.channels = arrUserId;


NSNotificationCenter* nctr1 = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[nctr1 addObserver: self selector: @selector(replicationProgressScore:)
              name: kCBLReplicationChangeNotification object: objAppDelegete.pull];

[objAppDelegete.pull start];
}
```

I have tried to call this function with NSThread as suggested in couchbase documentation

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: @selector(prepareCouchBaseAuthentication) toTarget:self  withObject: nil];
```

But after sometime it stop syncing ? is there any exception while syncing. How can i check if any exception occured?

My requirement is continuous  sync live feed from couchserver. Yes it will drain battery.
Is there any suggestion to do this?

Comment: How i can create the couch base lite documents in the background thread? Need help

Answer (score 3):

- **Running continuously:** there is a property called `continuous` on the replicator object (it's enabled in your code sample) which tells it to listen for changes on the local database (for a push replication) and remote database (for a pull replication). This will continuously get changes until you call `replication.stop()`.
- **Running continuously in the background:** It gets a bit tricky to run a replication continuously in the background (when the app is closed). I wrote a post on using the background fetch API on iOS (http://blog.couchbase.com/ios-background-fetch-to-sync-hacker-news-stories). The OS will periodically wake up the background fetch service and initiate a one-shot pull replication. Another way would be to start the replication when receiving a silent push notification from the server.